# Is Skateboarding ontopic?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

We've the tags [surfing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surfing) and [snowboarding](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snowboarding). Especially "snowboarding" implies that skateboarding should be definitely on-topic since it evolved from it.

> The development of snowboarding was inspired by skateboarding, (...)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowboarding)

Skateboarding, however, doesn't really feel like it would "fit in", does it? You don't really do it in "the great outdoors" but in the streets and specific parks.

And what about [longboarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longboarding) then? I think things like "downhill" and "travel" would work just perfectly.

> Longboards can be used for traveling long distances. (...) Any skateboard can be used for long distance journeys, however, decks designed specifically for long distance trips are typically lower to the ground than regular top mounted longboards. (...)

---

I think both topics are big topics and would probably attract new users.

Comment: hmmm, good question.... I'm not sure.

Comment: What kind of questions would you have in mind?  Perhaps they fit better on [Sports.SE].

Comment: Why would a skateboarding question be better here than on Sports SE?  Why would a skateboarding question be better on Sports SE than here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes Skateboarding is on topic. Besides being a relative of many clearly in scope activities as you indicate in your question, it primarily happens outdoors.

To validate the scope question, write a good question and post it.  You can include a link to this Meta post.

Contrary to some perceptions, if a topic is in scope on another site, has no bearing on it's scope at this site.

Example cross site questions, both exist and sister site links are in the comments at each other.

- [Why is only one side of the Moon visible from Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16) on astronomy.se
- [Why does the Moon face Earth with the same side?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4116) on physics.se

> The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people who love outdoor activities
>   [Source](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Plus you skate, skateboard, snowboard and can even surf indoors as well as out. If one's on topic all should be!

Answer (score 4):

I feel skateboarding is off-topic as a general sport:

Some of the most common forms of it rely heavily on a fair amount of human-built infrastructure: skate parks with ramps, kickers, half-pipes etc; or at the very least some decent paved roads/stairs/rails etc. do perform all those fancy tricks on.

- Paved roads and skate parks are not 'the Great Outdoors' in my opinion.

While there are certain styles which could be on-topic (there are some downhill variants, or for example longboarding in the [travel] tag), I don't think the sport overall qualifies.

As for the connection between snowboarding and skateboarding: I really don't quite see why it matters that one sport might be derived from the other. Snowboarding is actually done in *The Outdoors<sup>(TM)</sup>*, and while most people use ski lifts etc. to get uphill, touring (i.e. manual ascent) is common enough, proving that infrastructure might be beneficial to snowboarding, but is in no means necessary.